# LWJGL IllegalStateException

Tags: java, exception, lwjgl

quite new to java / I have no experience with LWJGL at all.

I'm running Netbeans on MacOSX Yosemite for development.

For some reason I'm getting the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread.
    at org.lwjgl.system.macosx.EventLoop.checkFirstThread(EventLoop.java:20)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit(GLFW.java:426)
    at lwtest.LWTest.init(LWTest.java:56)
    at lwtest.LWTest.run(LWTest.java:37)
    at lwtest.LWTest.main(LWTest.java:124)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm running the sample code directly from :: http://www.lwjgl.org/guide (the only difference being the change of the class name from 'HelloWorld' to 'LWTest'.

Comment: Did you use VM options `-Djava.library.path="target/natives` or whereever your natives (dll's and so on for lwjgl) are?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not experienced with LWJGL, but I am experienced with java, and the error says "Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread". So when you run the command `java MyClass.class` in DOS, change it to `java MyClass.class -XstartOnFirstThread`

Comment: Like a said, I am not experienced with LWJGL, I'm afraid I can't explain it as all I did was read the error. Sorry

Comment: I don't think that there is Java version that is compatible with DOS.

Comment: No, not to work with Java, but if you are going old-school and using DOS to start the program.